# how to say that the ring has a stone

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

I want to tell in the story something like "Every ring had either red or blue stone in it".

But I don't like that facility. Is there a way to say it better?

The full set of sentences looks like this

*The woman moved her left hand. Kenta saw several rings on her fingers. Every ring was embedded with one red stone. Then Kenta saw that the woman had also rings on the right hand but with transparent ones.*

Comment: With a request of this sort, you need to say (a) **why** you don't like that; (b) what you would like -- what criteria are you using to accept an answer?

Comment: I want it sound somehow beatiful and not crude to create the effect of some magic or something like this. Even in my native language I am unable to explain it.

Comment: In that sentence, I would indeed suggest *set*. But "beauty and not crudity" are in the ear of the beholder, so that's inherently opinion-based, I'm afraid.

Comment: @user1432980 : Either a red or a blue stone bejeweled every ring the ring maker had ever wrought.

Comment: I like bejeweled approach

Comment: You might consider looking at the descriptions in the well-known fantasy book "The Lord of the Rings." Some passages are quoted on the following page: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/77533/which-nenya-ring-is-correct

Answer (score 2):

You could use [**set**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/set).

> 1.3 - to mount a precious stone in something, typically a piece of jewelry.

To use the word in your sentence; "Every ring was **set** with a red or blue stone".

Comment: Still sounds somehow rough. Something like `embed` could be better. But maybe there is some literature way.

Comment: I don't see any explicit problem with using embed but It would depend on the context in which you want to use the sentence.You should elaborate your question, especially if you already have other words in mind.